# Setting button image when selected and unselected

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am just trying to set the button image to toggle to different images in my IBAction:

```
if ([sender isSelected]) {
//1
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"icon_checkbox_up"];
    [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [sender setSelected:NO];
}
else {
//2
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"icon_checkbox_down"];
    [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

When I click on the button, the image changes accordingly (under the comment 2), after pressing the button again, the image just disappears. I'm not sure why that is. I've tried both UIControlStateSelected and UIControlStateNormal. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Stuart you are correct, it is nil and should be named selectedImage. Do you know what is causing it?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in the method and step through? Are either of the `UIImage` instances `nil`? Also, note that you only need to set the images for each state once during the setup of the button. Changing the selected state will cause the image to change to the image that was set for that state.

Comment: Yes, by setting `nil` for the selected/unselected image for a given state, you're saying that the button should have no image for that state. I suspect the specified image file name is wrong - do they have a file extension (e.g. ".png")?

Comment: I am using image.xcassets so .png is not necessary? I've also double checked the name. It is correct.

Comment: What @Stuart mentioned is correct. In the, if else condition remove the image  code i.e the first two lines leaving only the last line line in condition and the image set code should be done only once when you are allocating the button.

Comment: You must use `UIImage`'s `+imageNamed:` method to create an image from an .xcassets file.

Comment: @Stuart and manish_kumar thanks for your help. I've set the images for each state in XIB and removed the code for setting images. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

If your file name isn't wrong, you could try this way. Hope it helps!!

```
[buttn addTarget:self action:@selector(Selected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[buttn addTarget:self action:@selector(Unselected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttn addTarget:self action:@selector(Unselected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

-(void)Selected
{
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"icon_checkbox_up"];
    [buttn setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [buttn setSelected:NO];
}

-(void)Unselected
{
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"icon_checkbox_down"];
    [buttn setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttn setSelected:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to:

```
if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setSelected:NO];
}
else {
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

and set the images in XIB files for each UIControlState.